# In pyfirmata, how to set up a handler for string messages?

Tags: python, arduino

How do I set up a handler to receive messages in pyfirmata from the Arduino UNO?

I have the following Python code:

```
from logic.ModuleClass import Module
from events.EventDispatcherClass import Event
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
import pyfirmata

class Comm(Module):
    """
    Handles the communication between python and arduino
    AttachTo: ""
    """

    NAME = "Communicator"

    def __init__(self, port):
        super(Comm,self).__init__(Comm.NAME)
        self.board = Arduino(port)
        # start an iterator thread so that serial buffer doesn't overflow
        it = util.Iterator(self.board)
        it.start()

        self.board.add_cmd_handler(pyfirmata.pyfirmata.STRING_DATA, self._messageHandler)

    def _messageHandler(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print args

    def update(self):
        super(Comm,self).update()

    def writeData(self,data):
        #print data
        self.board.send_sysex(pyfirmata.pyfirmata.STRING_DATA,data)

    def dispose(self):
        super(Comm,self).dispose()
        try:
            self.board.exit()
        except AttributeError:
            print "exit() raised an AttributeError unexpectedly!"+self.toString()
```

On the Arduino, I'm sending a string with this:

```
Firmata.sendString("test");
```

I added the _messageHandler(self, *args, **kwargs) and I'm getting back a collection of what I assume are character codes. I'm new to python and I'm not so sure how I can get the original string that were send from the Arduino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

To convert the string that is send from the arduino to pyfirmata just use the following code in your python:

```
def _messageHandler(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print util.two_byte_iter_to_str(args)
```

That should return the string you're expecting.
FTW!